# Two Tables that are the same that needs to be updated (with max uptime)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where I currently gather data from different servers and tables into one table for an application. Every 5 minutes I delete my table and generate it new with select into.
This is not an optimal solution because if a user does something in the application in the second the table is newly generated he runs into an error.

Now my thought is to make a transfer table that my application reaches that only gets updates and inserts if not exists compared with primary key. But I can't get it to work.

TransferTable

| PNr | SurName | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | Tom |
| 3 | ABC | John |

Table

| PNr | SurName | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | Tom |
| 3 | QPR | John |
| 4 | IJK | Jim |

```
update transfertable tt
set tt.surname = t.surname,
    tt.name = t.name,
    tt.pnr = t.pnr
from transfertable tt
join table t on tt.pnr = t.pnr;

insert into transfertable (pnr, surname, name)
select t.pnr, t.surname, t.name from table t
where not exsits
       (select tt.pnr
        from transfertable tt
        where tt.pnr = t.pnr)
```

I am unsure if my solution is too complicated (I have to do this with 12-13 tables with more than 20 rows, every table has one primary key that I could compare) or would even work. Is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: No upsert, in my opinion, is the "smart" way (compared to say a `MERGE`). I would, however, suggest you wrap the above in a transaction and enable `XACT_ABORT`. You *probably* want the `UPDLOCK` and `SERIALIZABLE` hints against your target table in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Oh, and `update transfertable tt` iss't valid syntax. It's `UPDATE < Target Object | Target Object Alias >` You want `UPDATE tt` here.

Comment: See also this https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern. Also if you decide to swap the order of the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` then you need the locking hints on the *inside* of the `NOT EXISTS` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the schema swap method to accomplish this. You populate a shadow table in a shadow schema, with your updated data, then using an intermediate swap schema table to transfer the prod table into the swap schema, followed by transferring your shadow table into the prod schema. This is a metadata change so is very fast with minimal downtime.

For example you will have 3 tables

```
prod.MyTable
shadow.MyTable
swap.MyTable
```

1. Truncate and populate shadow.MyTable with your new data. Alternatively you can DROP and CREATE the shadow.MyTable.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE shadow.MyTable
INSERT INTO shadow.MyTable
SELECT * FROM #MyTempTableWithNewData
```

2. Perform schema swap

```
ALTER SCHEMA swap TRANSFER prod.MyTable
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER shadow.MyTable
ALTER SCHEMA shadow TRANSFER swap.MyTable
```

Reference

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/keeping-tables-online-during-loading-with-schema-swapping-using-ssis